# Canvas rectangle is not expanding in a setInterval animation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I tried to make a program using HTML canvas. I don't know what I did wrong, but my code does not work. My program is supposed to work like follows: The program will draw a square. Next, it will change the values of the variables used to create the square. I put a `setInterval` to run my function more than once. Yes, I am aware there is no `clearRect`. But still, the square should grow. How it actually works is like follows: It draws a red square and nothing else happens.

How can I resolve this problem?

```js
var x = 75;
var y = 75;
var w = 150;
var h = 150;
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var dx = -1
var dy = -1
var dw = 2
var dh = 2
var col = "#f00"

function size(v, min, max, d) {
  if (v > max || v < min) {
    d = -d;
  }
  v += d;
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  size(x, 0, 150, dx);
  size(y, 0, 150, dy);
  size(w, 0, 300, dw);
  size(h, 0, 300, dh);
}

setInterval(draw, 25)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px" style="border:1px solid #000"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that function parameters are passed by value, not reference. The `size()` function gets a local copy of number parameters. You need to return a value from the function and assign it to a variable in the calling scope.

The other issue is you'd like to change both `d` and `v` inside of one function. That requires global variables (bad idea), returning a data structure of some sort, or breaking up your logic into multiple functions. Here's one way to go:

```
function changeDir(d, v, min, max) {
  return v > max || v < min ? -d : d;
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

  // Change direction if necessary
  dx = changeDir(dx, x, 0, 150);
  dy = changeDir(dy, y, 0, 150);
  dw = changeDir(dw, w, 0, 300);
  dh = changeDir(dh, h, 0, 300);

  // Accumulate
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  w += dw;
  h += dh;
}
```